# golang csv remove duplicate if matching column values

Tags: csv, go

New to Golang and struggling to figure out how to remove duplicates in CSVs if a particular column value matches another rows.

My table has 3 columns 
name | band | year

If a persons name appears twices or more I just want them to output them the once.

I have only been able to output all the details in a for loop so I am guessing I need to push to a new array and compare from that?

Comment: yes imo, push only the name into a slice (`[]string`) then iterate. This avoids the overhead of a map, but you will have to iterate more. I wonder how a benchmark compares between a map and string solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add to @Kul's answer:

```
// i'm pretty sure struct{} is smaller in memory than bool:
known := make(map[string]struct{})
for name, band, year, err := parseMyLine(); err == nil; {
  _, ok := known[name]
  if !ok {
    known[name]=struct{}{}
    handleFirstSeenName(name, band, year)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do the comparison, it'll be better to use the names as keys in a `map[string]bool`.

This way you won't have to loop through all the previously added rows, for every new row you evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kul mentioned, You can use `map[string]bool` Your code should look like this

```
csvFile, err := os.Open("csvFile.csv")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

defer csvFile.Close()

reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)

var name string
var band string
var year string

nameExistMap := make(map[string]bool)

csvRawData, err := reader.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}


for r, row := range csvRawData {
    name = r[0]
    band = r[1]
    year = r[2]

    if _, exist := nameExistmap[name]; exist {
        continue
    } else {
        nameExistmap[name] = true
        //Do Your Output Here
    }
}
```